# Join field (Multi-type index error) - Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl, virtualbox

I would like to create an index with a 'join' field. I used the exact curl command supplied by the ES documentation:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my_index" -H 'Content-Type:                 
application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": { 
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "question": "answer" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

This is the resulting error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: cannot create join field [my_join_field] on multi-types index [my_index]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: cannot create join field [my_join_field] on multi-types index [my_index]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
      "reason" : "cannot create join field [my_join_field] on multi-types index [my_index]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I'm struggling to understand the error (and struggling to fix it) as I've specified a new index in which there are no other types. If I misspoke/mistyped, please don't hesitate to correct me `:D`.

`Edit`: The version used when this command was run is 5.6.11, but I am currently trying to run 6.4.1. I am unsure whether this will fix the error.

`Edit`: Question title updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here's the deal.

The version I listed above doesn't seem to have the join field behave itself, so I opted to upgrade. I did so by running the following commands:

1. `echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install elasticsearch`

Tee-hee, another time-wasting question.

`T. Okai`

Answer (score 0):

Join field can be used on ElasticSearch5 is you set `mapping.single_type` to true in the index settings. (cf. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/parent-join.html#parent-join)

You also must rename the document type name because it must not start with "_".